# restrict users directly redirecting to another page by editing url

Tags: php, html

I'm developing a simple web application, where users can edit their post by clicking the edit link.

where user is in the profile.php when user click on the edit post link which located on same page then it redirect to editpost.php?edit=4, the id post of 4 is allow user to edit.

problem: when user mess with the url by editing as editpost.php, then how can we not allow the user to editpost.php 
 by simply entering in the address bar by user

Comment: In `editpost.php` check to make sure that the person is authorized to edit the profile referenced by the value passed.

Comment: My first thought is to have some sort of a token that’s unique to each edit that must be present to access the page. A cookie, url param, etc. that if not available users cannot access the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the most simple things I think that you can do to improve your pages:

1. **Authorization:** check the user privilege at the beginning of your script. Users won't able to edit posts that they do not have editing permissions.
2. **Unique random IDs:** instead of showing the auto-increment ID (which is easy to guess), you can create another string column in the database and assign a random unique ID for each post. In your script, query the database based on that unique column instead of the primary id column. If a user is on `edit.php?uid=abz-723-random`, he/she won't able to guess the next available id to try.

Some types of tokens can be used, too. However, using token prevent a user from refreshing pages/sharing page easily. If you have little experience in working with tokens, I recommend against them.

Comment: thanks for your answer and helping me to improve and i have a another doubt, how not to allow users to edit.php page by editing the url edit.php?uid=abz-723-random

Comment: I'm afraid that you cannot prohibit users from editing the URL in the address bar. The random id prevent user from guessing the "next valid id". If they enter an invalid `id`, you should return an error page.

Answer (score -1):

First change your Edit post url

```
editpost.php?=edit=4
```

to

```
editpost.php?edit=4
```

then use Get method to grab edit post id or number for example

```
$editpostid=$_GET['edit'];
```

after that run your mysqli query with condition **where id='$editpostid'**
 .           Let me know if you don't understand

Comment: sorry for my mistake and my question is how not to allow user to the page editpost.php by editing the url editpost.php?edit=4

Comment: Sorry Krishna for miss-understanding . Have you got idea yet or not?